# Share button with different pages

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, share

I researche it quite a bit, and thus it seems simple, I couldnt find the answer.

So I have a website that has different articles,each with a custom facebook share button. Every time the user wants to share, I activate javascript sdk and it works. However it shares the opengraph tags that are defined in the header. How would I do that dynamically ? I want to share the specific content of the article ? Is opengraph the right way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that your use case is something like the main page in a blog,
where you wish to display several articles in the same page,
and have a like button for each one.
However, the way Facebook crawls your page, it looks at the open graph meta tags for this main page only.
You wish for each of the share buttons to be specific to each post instead.

Have a read of the instructions [on this page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button/)

In your situation, her is what you will need to do:

- Set the `data-href` attribute of the individual page that the share button is for
- For the individual pages, set the open graph meta tags appropriately

This way, when facebook queries your page open graph meta tags, it will not do so on the main page, but instead on the pages you have specified.

---

Another approach, that will give you more fine grained control, would be to use Facebook's Javascript SDK.

The one that you are looking for, in this case, would be the [Share Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog).

Essentially, here you create your own buttons by hand, and trigger the Facebook Share API using Javascript manually too.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, so each article should have a different header ? Since the opengraph tags have to be in the head section if the html

Comment: Each article should have its own HTML page served at a different URL. However, you can put share buttons for these articles on your main page.